# Add new filter in the Panel column of the Product Catalogue

Tags: product, configurable-product, catalog, filter, catalogsearch

I want to add a new search filter in the product admin panel, but I don't know where to enable this option, if anyone has any idea if this can be enabled per individual user or only the super admin can make these changes.

[image]

I leave the image of the options so that you can tell me where I have to go to enable this option.

[image]